# Is there an online pdf or study that lists the MA(p) for p=1, 2, 3, ..., characteristically?

Tags: r, arima

Currently I'm recoding the arima functon in r, but for that the characteristic description of the MA(p)-s are needed.
For example:
MA(1):
Y1 = Theta(0)
Y2 = Theta(0) + Theta(1)*Y1 - Theta(1)*Theta(0)
.
.
.

I tried writing it down on paper but after Y(6) it gets really long. So a study about it would be needed where it's already written down.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Your formula for MA(p) model is wrong.
Please, see here: https://otexts.com/fpp2/MA.html, the book by Rob J Hyndman and George Athanasopoulos